# Erro ao tentar acessar a página ASP NET MVC C#: " HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio

Oi, gente, um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Meu projeto é ASP NET MVC5 com C#.

Fui criar mais uma página no meu projeto e simplesmente qdo eu rodo ela não é reconhecida. Fiz da mesma maneira que eu sempre fiz e não tá dando certo.

Aparece o erro " HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed".

Aqui é o Controller:

```
public class GruposDeUsuariosControllers : Controller
{
   
    public ActionResult RedirecionarPaginaDePesquisa()
    {
        GruposDeUsuariosViewModel modelo = new GruposDeUsuariosViewModel();
        try
        {
            return View("PaginaPesquisarGruposDeUsuarios", modelo);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TempData["MENSAGEM_ERRO"] = e.Message;
            return View("PaginaPesquisarGruposDeUsuarios", modelo);
        }
    }

}
```

A página está com o nome 'PaginaPesquisarGruposDeUsuarios.cshtml', está dentro do caminho "Views/GruposDeUsuarios" e não tem praticamente nada no conteúdo, somente:

```
<h1>Página</h1>
```

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2012 (sim, bem antigo, mas o cliente só tem esse) e não sei mais o que fazer REAL.

Parece alguma coisa bem boba ou bug msm.

Quem puder me ajudar ficarei mto agradecida, pois é urgente isso :(

Obrigada desde já!

Comment: qual url está usando pra acessar a página?

Comment: Se vc não está retornando a mesma view da actionResult, seria interessante vc usar o RedirectToAction ("ActionQueRetornaView", "NomeDoSeuControlador")

Comment: então, o problema é que nem chega a entrar no método

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar o **RedirectToAction**, pois pelo que entendi você não está retornando a view a action atual e sim uma outra view de um outro controller. (essa é uma das alternativas, existem outras).

```
public class GruposDeUsuariosControllers : Controller
{
   
    public ActionResult RedirecionarPaginaDePesquisa()
    {
        GruposDeUsuariosViewModel modelo = new GruposDeUsuariosViewModel();
        try
        {
            //Primeiro é a nome da Action e o segundo o nome controller
             RedirectToAction ("PaginaPesquisarGruposDeUsuarios", GruposDeUsuarios)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TempData["MENSAGEM_ERRO"] = e.Message;
            //Primeiro é a nome da Action e o segundo o nome controller
              RedirectToAction ("PaginaPesquisarGruposDeUsuarios", GruposDeUsuarios)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: eu mudei, mas ele nem entra no método

Comment: coleque a mensagem da Exception que está gerando aqui nos comentarios

Comment: seria interessante vc colocar o controller, model e view tbm para que possamos entender a rota

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do que você disse que não chega a entrar neste método *RedirecionarPaginaDePesquisa*, verifique sua rota default e a chamada para esta action esta correta, normalmente a action default é setada com index, no seu caso deveria explicitar a rota completa.

```
routes.MapRoute(  
            name: "Default",  
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
            defaults: new { 
                          controller = "Home", 
                          action = "Index", 
                          id = UrlParameter.Optional
                      });
```

Talvez, este [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/action-method-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) possa lhe ser útil.

Comment: tá da mesma forma...